# Making switching between Ubuntu and Windows faster

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, boot

Do you know a way to make switching between Windows and Linux faster?

I have a dual boot set-up were I am using Ubuntu as a dev environment and that's great l!

But unfortunately I also need Skype for business occasionally so I will need to reboot the PC for that.

The issue with that is booting into Windows 10 takes like 3 minutes (time until the boot menu comes up, booting itself, starting Windows docker etc. ).

I would love to know if there is a way to keep windows somehow in stand by or have it hibernate so it will boot faster. Also I think that another reason for startup being so slow is the fact that i had to disable fast boot because i have a shared partition between the two and i need to have it accessible on both systems.

Comment: A do have and ssd, i was thinking maybe there is some way to keep windows programs in a state that can have them quickly  resumed

Comment: No that's not possible.

Comment: Because you should not Hibernate Windows if booting another OS, because the disk will be left in a different state than after hibernation, you're pretty much stuck with Windows' slow boot time. On my HD-based system, Ubuntu takes ~90 seconds from cold boot through login, but Windows takes about *7 minutes* to boot and to be able to do useful work, partly because the antimalware tools  check the drives after a cold boot.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik i guess i am stuck with this time then :/ Thanks for your response

Answer (score 0):

If you already have an SSD as your main OS. Then any other suggestion will be a waste of time/money. When you restart your computer to boot into another OS. It's not possible to keep the previous OS in a 'hibernation state'. Computers are not designed that way.

Then Your best option in my opinion is using your Ubuntu build in a virtual OS. VMware is the best software i've found to work consistently and flawlessly.

That way you'll never have to restart. And both can be running at the same time.

> The issue with that is booting into windows 10 takes like 3 minutes

I don't see how you have a SSD if it's taking you 3 minutes to boot. Mine takes 10 seconds. You might not have an SSD or you might want to replace it with something high end (ex: Samsung)

Comment: I might have used the wrong words there. When i say that it takes me 3 minutes to boot windows up, i meant it takes me 3 minutes to do any useful stuff on windows.

Comment: What exactly about the computer is not designed to make this possible? Sounds more like a software issue to me.

Comment: What a nonsense, of course you can keep previous OS in hibernation state, computers do designed that way. The issue is just not to allow access to hibernated data partitions and not mount them in other OS, or unmount shared partition before hibernaiton.

Comment: @sandric You can put windows 10 into hibernation, restart the computer, boot into Linux, restart once again, then re-enter back into the previous windows state? That's news to me regardless of what data is accessible or not. No one with any brains uses dual boot anymore, this isn't the 2000s anymore.

Comment: @florentinStemate I doubt your still running the same hardware anymore, BUT my guess is that you installed a new SSD on an old 5-10 year old laptop and expected a huge performance boost or something, I'm not sure. Because Any SSD on relatively modern computer hardware should boot win10 in 5-10 seconds MAX. What you define as "USEFUL" is another thing. It takes me 5-10s to get to the user screen. And another 3-4 seconds for all my applications to load. EVERYONE is different, Maybe you have 300 malware viruses and 4 different antivirus pieces of software loading up with your OS.

Comment: @OutdatedComputerTech Indeed I moved past that laptop and got myself a PC :D. I think that laptop had some hardware issues because a few months after I've created this thread it started to get stuck at the manufacturer logo (before I had a chance to do anything) and the only way past that was to restart the laptop multiple times.

Comment: @sandric I was able to access the data just fine by disabling fast startup in windows. The good news is we moved to Teams so I never actually had to use this dual boot + shared partition hack.